# Inserting acronyms

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Problem: translate words into acronyms where the acronym of a word:

1. Has a prefix of at least one character.
2. Has a suffix of at least one character.
3. The remaining characters in the middle are replaced with a number representing how many middle characters where replaced.
4. The number of middle characters replaced must be >0 if the word has length >2.
5. Every acronym uniquely maps to one word. For example if "abide" => "a3e", then subsequently, "aside" cannot also translate to "a3e". It could either be as2e or a2de.

Some examples:

```
localization => l10n
```

or

```
localization => loc8n
```

or

```
localization => l8ion
```

What is a good approach for solving this problem? What sort of data structures would be bested suited? e.g.: `HashSet`? `Tree`?

Comment: What is the problem? As you said a word can translate into multiple acronym, and an acronym can map to multiple words. What's the input and what's the output?

Comment: the question is what is a good way to implement what is described.

Comment: I have a very simple algorithm: map every word to itself with a `0` stuck somewhere in the middle. Or, with less snark: how do you rank the "good-ness" of potential solutions to this problem?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to add the restriction of the middle number having to be >= 1. I rank goodness in terms of space and runtime complexity, simplicity, and less measurable elegance. what data structure might be best suited.

Comment: Problem is ambiguous/unsolvable in some cases: "hot", "hat" -> In some scenarios there is not enough space in "middle number" space to map all combinations of [a-z] that exist in words with same length, suffix and prefix onto. These will only occur at small words lengths. So amending the problem statement to say replace if possible, otherwise leave it would fix things.

Answer (score 0):

I will make some observations, though I don't have a really crushingly obviously great idea for a solution. As usual in the CS literature, I'll use "string" for a sequence of letters, and "language" for a set of strings.

- We might as well consider only alphabets whose strings are a fixed length. After all, none of the abbreviations for "localization" can possibly equal any of the abbreviations for "lotion".
- It is certainly possible for there to be no solution. The language {acb, adb, aeb} can't be abbreviated correctly by your rules -- nor even can the language {ab}. This doesn't really affect the algorithm, per se, but it is worth keeping in mind as you write your code and tests.
- Given a language, we can describe any abbreviation of the language by following this procedure:

  1. If the language is empty: stop, we're done and we succeeded!
  2. If the language contains length-2 strings or shorter: stop, we're done and we failed.
  3. Partition the language into sublanguages whose strings all start with the same letter and all end with the same letter. For example, {ready, robby, roady, legal, loyal, regal, royal} would be partitioned into the three languages {ready, robby, roady} (all of whose strings start with 'r' and end with 'y'), {legal, loyal} (all of whose strings start with 'l' and end with 'l'), and {regal, royal} (all of whose strings start with 'r' and end with 'l').
  4. For each sublanguage (for example, {ready, robby, roady}):

     1. Choose a string to fully abbreviate; for example, we might choose "ready". Then emit the abbreviation and its mapping; in this case "r3y" and "ready".
     2. Choose the right- (respectively, left-) derivative of the language minus the string we've emitted an abbreviation for, and start again from step 1. Add the last (resp. first) letter to each abbreviation emitted by the recursive step. For example, if we chose the left derivative here, we would add 'r' to the beginning of all the abbreviations emitted by recursing on the language {obby, oady}.

  You might be slightly concerned that step 4-1 isn't quite right; perhaps it is sometimes necessary to do *all* abbreviation in the recursive step. But it's easy to see this is not so: if we have to do that, we can certainly "improve" the abbreviation (in the sense that the total number of elided letters increases) by choosing any one of the recursive abbreviations and promoting it as proposed by step 4-1 without causing any clashes.

  This immediately suggests a search algorithm that can walk through all valid abbreviations. I leave it to you whether you want to find the "best" abbreviation by some metric, or just want to find one. In the latter case, the order you try choices in step 4 probably affects the quality of the first abbreviation you find significantly, though off the top of my head I don't see any principled way of choosing -- only heuristics.
- Minimal DFAs support all the operations necessary (emptiness tests, partitioning, representative choice or enumeration, and right- and left-derivatives) with fair time efficiency, and are quite space efficient.

Answer (score 0):

**Restating the question:** Find a *one to one mapping* from a set of words to the set of "acronyms" (as defined above). Each word may be represented as *prefix*|*middle*|*suffix*. However each word, can map to exactly *M(M+1)/2* acronyms where *M* is the length of the *middle*. Example "hot" can map only to "h1t", heat can map to 2(2+1)/2 = 3 acronyms - "h1at", "he1t", "h2t". So the problem is to arbitrarily (due to lack of any stated fitness metric) choose a unique value from the range of valid acronyms for each word. The problem solution is easier (and better) if we assume a greedy policy for replacing middle character. I.e. replace as many middle letters as possible. Note there may since many words can map to the same set of acronyms there may not be enough acronyms to assign one acronym to each word. In this case we assume we just assign the word itself as its acronym.

**Approaches & data structures:** It's often best to define a pseudo-code solution to your problem then ask what ADT (abstract data types) could be used, then ask what is the most appropriate implementation of the ADT. In this case you need to represent a mapping with an intractably large key space (English words). In general, given this requirement you'd think about a "dictionary", where a dictionary is a ADT that supports three operations: `insert(key, value`, `delete(key)`, `search(key)` (you don't need `delete()` in this application). Dictionaries are commonly implemented as [hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). The good thing about thinking in terms of the ADT first is the underlying implementation can be swapped out and doesn't effect you reasoning.

Note, your key space in this instance has some structure to it; each word has three weak keys - it's length, prefix, suffix - that together map a word onto a unique acronym. You could exploit that to create an application specific nested dictionary, but most people wouldn't bother in most applications and would just use your language of choices string dictionary implementation as it's simple and probably fast enough.

Here is a simple solution using [Python's dictionary type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping). Solution uses the "greedy on middle part length" approach to searching for an acronym for a given word, and falls through to a word to word mapping if no acronym is found:

```
class Acronym():
  ''' Convenience class to rep the acronyms of a word. ''' 
  word = None

  def __init__(self, word):
    self.word = word

  def __iter__(self):
    ''' Loop over the M(M+1)/2 possible acronyms largest middle first. '''
    for m in reversed(range(1,len(self.word) - 1)):
      for i in range(1,len(self.word) - m):
        yield (self.word[0:i], str(len(self.word[i:i+m])), self.word[i+m:])

my_acronyms = {} # my_acronyms is a Python dictionary
my_words = ["hot", "hit", "hard", "heat", "have", "hoon", "halve"];
for word in my_words:
  acronym = Acronym(word)
  found_acronym = False
  for split in acronym:
    if not my_acronyms.get(''.join(split)): # search(key)
      my_acronyms[''.join(split)] = word
      found_acronym = True
      break
  if not found_acronym:
    my_acronyms[word] = word # insert(key, value)
print(my_acronyms)
```

Comment: N.B. because this algorithm greedily commits on any success, it may not find abbreviations even when it is possible to. For example, with `my_words = ["aaaa", "acba", "adca", "abca", "abba"]`, it commits to abbreviations for the first four words that prevents it from abbreviating `abba`, whereas it is possible to create a mapping which abbreviates all the words. Presumably it is also possible to cook up an example that shows that considering possible splits in a fixed order as done here is a problem.

Comment: @DanielWagner: The OP uses the word "subsequently" in describing how selecting an acronym for "abide" will block using the same acronym for "aside"; so I think (s)he is in fact asking for a greedy/online/realtime algorithm.

Comment: @DanielWagner I interpreted it the way ruakh did. But it's worthy point. Then again, although an abbreviation could be found for all cases in your example, is it any better in term of over all efficiency - where efficiency is information saved by replacing letters with a number? I haven't proved the greedy is optimal, but by this metric it does a better in your example.

Comment: @spinkus I explicitly asked for a good metric to evaluate solutions by and was rebuffed. So I don't know whether the asker would consider "information saved" a good metric or not! Even so, I would be quite surprised if the greedy algorithm was optimal for that metric, either.

Comment: Yeah I just assumed greedy in lack of any other info. Updated question with restated problem definition - originally left it out coz TL;DR. On optimality of greedy; not sure, inclined to agree. Shouldn't be too hard to come up with a counter example. Yet, I can't off the top of my head.